# Laravel Query Builder Return Results

Tags: laravel

I have below Laravel Query, which runs very fine and returns the desired results.

```
 $email = (Auth::user()->email);
    $UerType = DB::table('tbl_schools')->where('email', $email)->pluck('type');
    $parent_ids = DB::table('tbl_schools')->where('email', $email)->pluck('id');
    // return $parent_ids;

    if ($UerType == 'sub_admin') {
        $children = DB::table('tbl_schools')->whereIn('id', $parent_ids)->get();
        return $children;
    } elseif ($UerType == 'school') {
        $children = DB::table('tbl_schools')->where('email', $email)->get();
        return $children;
    } elseif ($UerType = 'admin') {
        $children = DB::table('tbl_schools')->where('email', $email)->get();
        return $children;
    }
```

Out from Above is as expected

```
{
"id": 15,
"type": "sub_admin",
"parent_id": "12",
"username": "",
"access_role_type": "SCH2486518",
"school_code": "SCH2486518",
"school_name": "Test School",
"school_ad_name": "Support",
"address": "",
"email": "someemail@mail.com",
"mobile": "+2332123123123",
"school_logo": "",
"profile_image": "",
"status": "active",
"created": "2020-09-28 16:41:44",
"updated": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
"token": ""
}
```

Now I need to Pick specific fields and save them to session for future use, but when I run the below code, strangely I still get the entire Query Result which is strange.

```
$email = (Auth::user()->email);
    $UerType = DB::table('tbl_schools')->where('email', $email)->pluck('type');
    $parent_ids = DB::table('tbl_schools')->where('email', $email)->pluck('id');
    // return $parent_ids;
    if ($UerType == 'sub_admin') {
        $children = DB::table('tbl_schools')
        ->select('id','type','parent_id','school_name')
        ->whereIn('id', $parent_ids)
        ->get();
        return $children;
    } elseif ($UerType == 'school') {
        $children = DB::table('tbl_schools')
        ->Select('id','type','parent_id','school_name')
        ->where('email', $email)
        ->get();
        return $children;
    } else  {
        $children = DB::table('tbl_schools')
        ->Select('id','type','parent_id','school_name')
        ->where('email', $email)
        ->get();
        return $children;
    }
```

I need help

Comment: This is the actual code or you removed something to fit on stack overflow?

Comment: It makes no sense because $UerType will be an array and you are comparing it against a string. Also you should not repeat yourself like this, 50% of your code is repeated code

Comment: That's the entire code for that purpose. Also on the $UerType can you Please advise?

Comment: btw, if you want a single value from a record you can use the `value` method not `pluck`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need to call the same query two times. Next, you are returning an array and compare it with a string. Do the following way. Hope this will give you the exact result.

```
$email = (Auth::user()->email);
$user = DB::table('tbl_schools')->where('email', $email)->first();

if ($uerType->type == 'sub_admin') {
    $children = DB::table('tbl_schools')->whereIn('id', $user->id)->get();
    return $children;
} elseif ($user->type == 'school') {
    $children = DB::table('tbl_schools')->where('email', $email)->get();
    return $children;
} elseif ($user->type = 'admin') {
    $children = DB::table('tbl_schools')->where('email', $email)->get();
    return $children;
}
```